# Access build information from custom build results tab

Tags: plugins, teamcity

In TeamCity 8 I have written a plugin that adds a custom tab to the build results using this code:

```
public class BuildUtilitiesTab extends SimpleCustomTab 
{
    public BuildUtilitiesTab(@NotNull PagePlaces pagePlaces, @NotNull final PluginDescriptor descriptor) 
    {
        super(pagePlaces, PlaceId.BUILD_RESULTS_TAB, "buildUtilitiesTab", descriptor.getPluginResourcesPath("buildUtilities.jsp"), "Build Utilities");
        register();
    }
}
```

This adds a tab called "Build Utilities" to the build results alongside "Overview", "Changes", "Build Log" etc. Clicking this tab launches my JSP file buildUtilities.jsp. I want to display the build machine and the checkout location.

I think I should be able to write the following:

```
<jsp:useBean id="build" type="jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.SBuild" scope="request">
```

Which is used by TeamCity's BuildOverview.jsp page. However I get the following ception:

```
ERROR -   jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - Error java.lang.InstantiationException: bean build not found within scope while processing request: GET '/buildLog/viewLog.jsp?buildTypeId=Abc_Abc&buildId=1&tab=redGateTeamCityBuildUtilitiesTab', from client 127.0.0.1:64038, authenticated as david, original page URL: /viewLog.html?buildTypeId=Abc_Abc&buildId=1&tab=redGateTeamCityBuildUtilitiesTab
    java.lang.InstantiationException: bean build not found within scope
```

Does anyone know how you are supposed to use beans in this context, or if there is another way to access the information?

Answer (score 0):

```
<jsp:useBean id="buildData" type="jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.SBuild" scope="request">
```

The id should be "buildData" not "build".

With thanks to Maxim Podkolzine of JetBrains.